scikit-multiflow installation issue in ubuntu
I have tried to install scikit-multiflow lib in my system. I have all the libraries updated. But I'm facing an issue with  'numpy.distutils. .  Anyone fixed this before? python version: Python 3.12.3.
$ pip install scikit-multiflow
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting scikit-multiflow
  Using cached scikit-multiflow-0.5.3.tar.gz (450 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-0ooond15/scikit-multiflow_ee182699010f4b65b5f640551f09596d/setup.py", line 136, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-0ooond15/scikit-multiflow_ee182699010f4b65b5f640551f09596d/setup.py", line 128, in setup_package
          from numpy.distutils.core import setup
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.distutils'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I came to know that distutils is not avialable in updated numpy. Even I tired to downgrade the verision still facing issue.

"Even I tired to downgrade the verision still facing issue.": that may be because scikit-multiflow downloads its own dependencies for the installation (building of a wheel/binary from the source file on your system). And apparently, they have not tested this properly, by limiting the valid NumPy version for local builds. This is a guess, since I don't know the details, but it sounds like a bug in scikit-multiflow.

Provided your currently installed NumPy version is the downgraded one (probably < 2.0), you can try to install with pip install --no-build-isolation scikit-multiflow. That will require that you have all build dependencies installed beforehand. But the error message(s) should reveal which one are still missing, which is an easy fix. (Basically, check the packages in the  requirements.txt and requirements-dev.txt files from the repository, taking care to put an upper limit on the major version as well.)

I will point out that the last update to the repository was on 19 November, 2020. Basically, this package has been abandoned. Installing it with any recent Python and packages will become more and more problematic over time. In fact, the Python versions supported according to setup.py are 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8. So you may have to go back in time for it to properly install and function. And your hardware and OS may also have to go back in time.
